# MySql Table is taking up a lot of space

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

Hello I have a table that records users activity (**logs**) at the moment I have a total of **260,884** rows in this table and it is taking up 278.9 MB space, so my question is why is it taking up so much space is there something wrong with the table structure ?

Example for 1 row

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "event_type": "updated",
    "subject_type": "Api\\Utils\\Notes\\Models\\Note",
    "subject_id": 1853,
    "causer_type": "Api\\Users\\Models\\User",
    "causer_id": 1080177,
    "properties": "{\"new_attributes\": {\"id\": 24959, \"email\": \"test@gmail.com\", \"b2b_id\": 87, \"address\": \"PAITILLA CALLE WINSTON CHURCHILL EDIFICIO THE POINT\", \"last_name\": \"GONZALEZ GARCIA\", \"created_at\": \"2020-10-16 15:52:24\", \"first_name\": \"JANI INDIRA\", \"package_id\": 1000034425, \"updated_at\": \"2020-10-16 15:52:24\", \"xa_vendor_id\": 1, \"xa_service_id\": 2, \"destination_id\": 1001, \"ordering_number\": \"0013\", \"category_metrics_id\": 1, \"reference_of_address\": \"nr\"}}",
    "created_at": "2020-10-16 15:23:54",
    "updated_at": "2020-10-16 15:23:54"
}
```

Table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `logs` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `event_type` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `subject_type` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `subject_id` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `causer_type` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `causer_id` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `properties` json DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `subject` (`subject_type`,`subject_id`),
  KEY `causer` (`causer_type`,`causer_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=290528 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Answer (score 2):

Row size ignoring json is about 630 bytes.
630 x 260,000 = about 163,000,000

Accordingly, the 250MB are reasonable.

If you have a well defined schema, you are better off extracting the field values and storing them in table columns.

Depending on what you want to do with the log and how often, and what problem you face, you might consider other options including a simple text file.

Comment: The 630 is pessimistic.  For example the example shows a row with only 9 bytes consumed by the `event_type` column.  Also, the 630 is optimistic.  If each varchar had 191 emoji, each would take 766 bytes (2+4*191).

Comment: @RickJames Just an estimate.

Answer (score 1):

In your sample row, `properties` is taking over 500 bytes.  If that is typical, then, *per row*:

- 500 bytes for the json
- 200 bytes for the other columns
- 100 bytes for the *each* secondary indexes
- miscellany overhead

That easily adds up to 1KB.

1KB * 260,884 ~= 278.9 MB

If that is "too big", then one approach is to compress the JSON string *in the client* and store it into a `BLOB`.  (That will not allow you to use any json functions.)  That would shrink the disk footprint by about half.

Comment: Compression is a good idea but it all depends on use case. It will prevent easy querying. Maybe he can just live with the current situation as is.